# Allowing an image to overflow outside the DIV?

Tags: html, css, image, overflow

Basically, I just need a part of this "N" be slight overflown outside the container.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8w4a.jpg)

It is like this:

```
<span style="position: relative; display: inline-block">
<img src="n.png" style="position: absolute; overflow: visible !important; z-index: 10000; display: block" />
Neke od...
</span>
```

Whatever I did, `<IMG />` won't overflow the parent `<DIV />`...

Comment: Can I do it by overflowing as I specified?

Comment: You could try using negative margins or negative positioning (such as `margin-top: -20px` or `top: -20px`).

Comment: No, I can not, because it just keeps clipping for the amount of -20px... The negative margins keep going into `overflow: hidden`. I also tried `z-index`, but No.

Comment: If you have overflow: hidden on the div, then it's game over.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.